# How do I add the text data from a single cell in a google sheets doc into html to be displayed on a website?

Tags: html, google-sheets

I am using sheets as a basic server and want to change the text from one place, have that text populate a cell in sheets, and then display on a new site.  I have already figured out how to use importxml to get the data I need into the sheet.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a job for Google Web Apps, with this you can create a web page and use your spreadsheet as a database, or build your own API and return your spreadsheet data as text,JSON,XML,etc...

More info here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web